# Is there a way to open Excel files from a folder, perform actions, then close or delete the files using a VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to;

- obtain a list of files from a specific source folder (e.g. D:\My Drive\EM SSC\PA\AttNew)
- open the first source file (all Excel files, all the exact same format)
- run a macro that copies certain fields from the opened file into a data table (I already have this working for a single (named) file) on a different Excel file (C:\Users\r5\Documents\DataFile_v1.xlsx)
- close the source file (an ideally delete it or move it to a different folder)
- open the next source file from the list
- continue until all source files are dealt with
- save the data table file

New Excel source files are automatically copied into the source folder each day, so I need to open each source file, copy data to my table and then remove the files, ready for the next days files.

I have only been able to complete the steps related to copying the data fields from a single source file to the data table. I am unsure of how to do the iterative part to open one file after another. I am not an experienced VBA user. I need to open a source file, copy data from it to my table, then close/delete the source file and move on to the next source file.

Comment: Why don't you share the code you got so far (for one file)?

Answer (score 1):

Use Task Scheduler to run a bat file that runs a .vbs to open and runs macros in your excel file. [Explanation and example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc019p2Ptc4&ab_channel=SigmaCoding)

The bat file will contain something along the lines of
"D:\My Drive\EM SSC\PA\AttNew\Automation.vbs"

The .vbs file would be something along the lines of

```
Set xlsxApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsxApp.Visible = True

Set xlsxWorkbook = xlsxApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\My Drive\EM SSC\PA\AttNew\AutomationProject.xlsm")
xlsxApp.Run("Macro1") 'Name of your macro
```

Closing your workbook would contain something like this, in your ThisWorkbook VBA editor

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 'Closes all other 
worksheets par "MainSheet", saves user time not having to delete 
imported sheets everytime

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If ws.Name <> "MainSheet" Then 'If a worksheet is not named "MainSheet" it gets deleted
ws.Delete
End If

Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox ("All sheets are deleted except specific sheet - After this, you 
can click either 'Save' or 'Don't Save' button") 'Message box to reasure user is okay with either option when closing the file

End Sub
```

I am not sure about next stages, but let me know how this works so far

Comment: Thanks EuanM28, I am going to try this. Very new to me, but appreciate the help and suggestions.